# TFS throwing errors by mails after files checked in but not during building project

Tags: c#, tfs

I am working on a signalr project. I took a backup of entire solution before making a change. Now while checking in changes from the original version TFS throws some errors through mail. These errors were not while building the solution. I actually installed the signalr package in backup solution. But i added refernce to the dlls. Still showing errors as below.

```
Minor | Any CPU
22 error(s), 4 warning(s) 
$/FEPS/Source/Development/FEPS/Payroll.sln - 22 error(s), 4 warning(s) 
Objects\ChatHub.cs(1):The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
.
.
.
```

Is adding refernce to DLLs enough or it should be installed in the solution?

Expected build success.

Comment: Namesapaces can be nested like System.Data.SqlClient.  System, Data, and SqlClient are all namespaces and can be separate libraries (dll files).  So it looks like you have the Microsoft.dll on the machine but not the AspNet.dll.  The code is looking for the namespace Microsoft.AspNet.

Comment: Hi ViKi, are you even not able to build succeed locally? If so , this seems more related to visual studio and C#. Besides, we do not suggest to directly check in dlls to source control and refer them.  Please use Nuget to manage these dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. It has been resolved.

This is what happened... I had checked in the DLLs to a path in TFS which was outside the scope of the solution, which was restricted. So, though the path to DLLs in references were correct, TFS could not copy the DLLs to the bin folder. I figured it out and checked in DLLs to correct path and then DLLs were copied correctly to bin.

All errors got cleared !

Thank you once again.